# Make my own link_to in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm a new Rails developer and this my first question here so please be gentle.

I've been using Twitter Bootstrap in my application to put tooltips and Glyphicons on buttons on my CRUD links as follows:

Show:

```
<%= link_to master_group, class: "btn btn-default", data: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "left"}, title: "Show" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>
<% end %>
```

Edit:

```
<%= link_to edit_master_group_path(master_group), class: "btn btn-default", data: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "left"}, title: "Edit" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span>
<% end %>
```

Destroy:

```
<%= link_to master_group, method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?',toggle: "tooltip", placement: "left" }, class: "btn btn-default", title: "Delete" do %>
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span> 
<% end %>
```

Would it be possible make my own versions of link_to, so I could just change the path in each call, for example:
link_to_show master_group 
link_to_edit edit_master_group_path(master_group)
link_to_destroy master_group

I was trying to follow the Rails DRY principles and found myself repeating this code for each view. I was also conscious that if for example, I wanted to change the tooltip, I'd have to do it on every single view. It would also allow me to be certain that my application had good uniformity.

Could anyone help me please.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The fact is that you are not only changing path but also the glyphicon shown so you can't reuse the same code for those 3 links, unless you want to evaluate the path and show the proper glyphicon based on the path

Comment: I'm happy to have a link_to for each button if needed. E.g. link_to_show, link_to_delete etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create your custom link_to(s) in ApplicationHelper

**Example**

```
module ApplicationHelper

  def link_to_show(path)
    link_to path, class: "btn btn-default", data: {toggle: "tooltip", placement: "left"}, title: "Show" do 
      '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search"></span>'.html_safe
    end
  end

end
```